# How do I send a response to a MQTT message?

Tags: python, mqtt

I would like one RaspberryPi-A to send a massage to RaspberryPi-B, and RaspberryPI-B should send a massage back automatically. I know this is a beginners question, but I'm one and I have really struggled all day trying to find an anwser.

This is my client's code

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

MQTT_SERVER = "localhost"
MQTT_PATH = "test_channel"


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))


client.subscribe(MQTT_PATH)

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    # more callbacks, etc

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)


client.loop_forever()
```

And this is my publisher’s code

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

MQTT_SERVER = "192.168.1.5"
MQTT_PATH = "test_channel"

publish.single(MQTT_PATH, "Hello World!", hostname=MQTT_SERVER)
```

How should i write the code differently so my client would return the massage for example: "Hello back"?

Comment: A good question should also show the specific error or problem you have (text of an exception if you get one, for example), rather than just showing your existing code with no description of how it fails to work; see the [mcve] definition.

Comment: (Similarly, and per that same page, code samples should be the shortest thing that *lets someone actually reproduce the same issue themselves* -- so if you're going to have a `# more stuff here` commented-out section, you need to be sure the code still works enough to show the problem with that comment in place).

Comment: This code doesn't have a problem. I would just like RaspberryPI-B to be able to anwser to a question from RaspberryPi-A. I'm just a begineer in programming so I really don't know how to change this code to be able to do that.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want a different channel for responses, then, so the other system can send the answer on it? There's nothing required code-wise you don't already have -- just need to copy the code you already have for subscribing and listening into the client so it can listen for a response, changing the channel identifier to a different one.

Comment: I would like RPI-B to automatically respond to a massage from RPI-A. So if i use a different channel, will it still bi able to respond automatically?

Comment: If A listens on channel A, and B listens on channel B, then anything that B sends on channel A will be read by A, and anything A sends on channel B will be read by B. Make sense? So you have B listen on channel B, and send responses on channel A.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just a little confused. I wrote one code on RPI-A terminal and second code on RPI-B terminal. After i type mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.55 -v -t test_channel on RPI-B and mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.55 -t test_channel -m "Hello Raspberry Pi" on RPI-A, i send a massage from A to B. I would like B, after receiving a massage from A to respond and send a response to A.

Comment: So make your `on_message()` code send a message on the channel opposite the one you received your message from, and then the response will be received via a call to `on_message()` on the other side. Clear? Because you put it in your `on_message()` handler, it's called "automatically", as you request.

Comment: I think i understand. Tkank you, i will try it.

Comment: As was pointed out when you asked this question on the IoT site, we expect you to at least try and edit the examples before asking for help and to show us what you tried and explain why how it didn't work

Comment: How can I try if I didn't have any idea where to start. So i decided to ask this questions on Stack Overflow because is more of an beginners question. I think that this site is a bit unfriendly for beginners, it is really hard for me because it's my first time implanting communication protocol on a Raspberry Pi. But trust me, I always thoroughly search for answers online before posting unneeded questions. But I need to thank Charles Duffy for guiding me in right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of messaging models:

- Point to Point  (one to one) - a message is sent from one application to another application via a queue.  There can be more than 1 consuming (receiver) applications but only one of them will receive the message.
- Publish / Subscribe - is where a message is published to a topic and multiple consumers (subscribers) will **each** receive a copy of the message.  There can be 1 or more applications publishing messages to the same topic and 1 or more applications consuming (receiving) the messages.

MQTT is built on the Publish / Subscribe messaging model.

Your description sounds like you want Point to Point messaging.  Yes, you can bend MQTT to act like Point to Point but be aware that if you have multiple applications publishing messages to the same topic, you may get confused.

```
MQTT_PATH = "test_channel"
publish.single(MQTT_PATH, "Hello World!", hostname=MQTT_SERVER)
```

There is no such thing as a "channel" in MQTT.  Your code is publishing a message to the topic called: test_channel.

It is better to use a little hierarchy in your topic names.

i.e.

- pivk95/food/burgers
- pivk95/food/fries
- pivk95/food/pizza
- pivk95/food/burritos
- pivk95/drink/shakes
- pivk95/drink/soft_drink

Just remember that any number of applications can publish messages to a given topic and any number of applications can subscribe to a given topic and receive copies of the messages.